# "Camafeu" é um elogio ou uma palavra depreciativa?

Tags: significado, português-europeu

Estava a ler alguns blogs e me deparei com esta palavra. Inicialmente, pelo contexto, havia entendido que se tratava de algo pejorativo relativo a aparência, como afirma um dos significados do [priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/camafeu):

> ca·ma·feu
>   substantivo masculino
>   [...]
>   2. [Informal, Depreciativo]  Cara muito feia.

Porém, após pesquisa no [aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/camafeu), vi que também pode significar o oposto:

> (ca.ma.feu)
>   sm.
>   [...]
>   3. Pop. Mulher de feições finas: "Graciosíssima. O perfil é assim meio romano: > camafeu em cornalina..." (Guimarães Rosa, Sagarana.))
>   4. Joc. Pessoa muito feia
>   [F.: Do fr. camaïeu.]

Sei que tem outros significados, mas afinal, para estes dois em especial, qual é o mais utilizado? Chamar alguém de camafeu será considerado uma ofensa ou um elogio?

Comment: Não conhecia esses significados. Pra mim, **camafeu** sempre foi aquele [doce feito de nozes](http://www.tudogostoso.com.br/receita/2931-camafeu.html)

Comment: Tu poderias disponibilizar o blog onde estava lendo, de repente o contexto também ajuda a entender.

Comment: @Peixoto foi neste aqui, logo no inicio: http://porfalarnoutracoisa.sapo.pt/2017/05/ultima-consulta-traicoes-e-namorados.html

Comment: Muito interessante. Nesse caso específico, me parece que está sendo utilizado de forma pejorativa. Eu reescreveria da seguinte forma: *isso só faz sentido se tu fores **muito feia** e ele for o único gajo minimamente interessado em ti*
PS: O que significa IST?

Comment: Eu (de Portugal) conhecia *camafeu* como 'pessoa feia', mas é termo raro. No sentido de 'mulher bonita' nunca tinha ouvido; é possível que tenha esse sentido só no Brasil; não vem no dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa. @Peixoto *IST* é possivelmente Instituto Superior Técnico da Universidade de Lisboa.

Comment: @Hugo,de facto esse doce faz lembrar um [camafeu (no sentido primário)](https://www.google.pt/search?q=camafeu&num=50&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9-t7c757UAhXJuBoKHYglChwQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=662).

Comment: @Jacinto exceto pelo trecho do significado, nunca vi ninguem utilizar essa  palavra no brasil. Se em portugal ela significa o oposto do que Guimarães Rosa expressou, poderia ser um caso de "licença poética" correto?

Comment: Diego, o Guimarães Rosa, no meu entender, faz uma comparação, "Graciosíssima. O perfil é meio romano: [como um] camafeu em cornalina"; aqui, "camafeu em cornalina" é usado no sentido literal (cornalina é um tipo de ágata, uma pedra preciosa); Já andei a procurar e encontrei alguns exemplos desse tipo, "rostinho de camafeu" (os camfeus, a joia, tem frequentemente um rosto esculpido em baixo relevo); em todos os exemplos em que se chama "camafeu" a alguém, é no sentido de pessoa feia; mas só encontro em autores portugueses, especialmente do sXIX e princípio do XX>>

Comment: >> Eu conhecia a palavra nesse sentido, pessoa feia, mas é pouco usada atualemente.

Comment: @Peixoto o Jacinto tem razão, IST é o [Instituto Superior Técnico](https://tecnico.ulisboa.pt), uma escola de engenharia da Universidade de Lisboa.

Comment: Pra mim "camafeu" é um pingente de colar, exibindo uma face feminina esculpida em pedra preciosa ou semi-preciosa .  [**ver camafeu**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camafeu)  Nunca ouvi com outro significado.

Answer (score 2):

Em Portugal, a palavra "camafeu" é usada pejorativamente, com o sentido de *pessoa feia*.
Não é uma palavra muito comum.

O significado literal de camafeu¹ não seria reconhecido pela maioria das pessoas.

---

¹ "[camafeu](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/camafeu)" (consultado em 07-06-2017):

> 1. Pedra fina com duas camadas, diferentes na cor, uma das quais leva gravado um desenho em relevo.

Answer (score 0):

Para mim. Camafeu significou sempre uma joia de uso pessoal com um aspecto 'pesadão'. Joia elaborada mas de modo algum seria considerada feia. Era usada por senhoras de meia-idade o que acentuava o tal estigma de 'pesada'.